# Why can customize css abbreviation instead of html:5 in snippets.json?

Tags: html, css, emmet

My .vimrc setting on snippest.json.

```
let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('~/.vim/snippets.json')), "\n"))
let g:emmet_html5 = 1
```

The `ani` abbreviation setting in my `.vim/snippets.json`.

```
      "ani": "animation:|;",
```

The `ani` in css file can expand as `animation`,snippets.json can take effect.
I expect `html:5` expand as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Revise doc defination in my snippets.json as below:

```
"doc": "html>(head>(meta[charset=${charset}]+title+link))+body",
```

Why `html:5` still expand as  below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Why abbreviation setting for `html:5` in snippets.json can't take effect ?
And i can revise the string in the file `.vim/autoload/emmet.vim`  as below:

```
\            'html:5': "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
\                    ."<html lang=\"${lang}\">\n"
\                    ."<head>\n"
\                    ."\t<meta charset=\"${charset}\">\n"
\                    ."\t<title></title>\n"
\                    ."\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"\"></link>\n"
\                    ."</head>\n"
\                    ."<body>\n\t${child}|\n</body>\n"
\                    ."</html>",
```

`html:5` can expand into my expectional format,it is not a good way in practice.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right, you have wrong syntax. 
Go to the file:

> lib/snippets.json

```
"doc": "html>(head>meta[charset=${charset}]+title{${1:Document}}+link)+body"
```

work's fine for me.

P.S. Don't forget to restart your code editor.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that your link declaration in `.vim/autoload/emmet.vim` has an `src=""` tag. That might be causing your glitches, and making the html not expand as you want it to.`

Comment: It is a typo when i revise `.vim/autoload/emmet.vim`.

Comment: My puzzle is why snippets.json can take effect for css instead of html ?